# Theano with opencl GPU

Tags: opencl, gpu, theano

I have configured `theano` as follows:

```
[idf@localhost python]$ more ~idf/.theanorc 
[global]
device = opencl0:0
floatX = float32

[lib]
cnmem=100
[idf@localhost python]$
```

I also needed to

```
[idf@localhost python]$ export MKL_THREADING_LAYER=GNU
```

although interestingly enough, if I install `openblas` and add

```
[blas]
ldflags = -lopenblas
```

to the `.theanorc file`, I no longer need to:

```
export MKL_THREADING_LAYER=GNU
```

Using a program I found on the internet which I modified slightly to use `gpuarray`, I am attempting to use `theano` with an `Intel` `GPU` through `opencl`:

```
import os
import shutil


from theano import function, config, shared, gpuarray
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy
import time

vlen = 10 * 30 * 768  # 10 x #cores x # threads per core
iters = 1000

rng = numpy.random.RandomState(22)
x = shared(numpy.asarray(rng.rand(vlen), config.floatX))

f = function([], T.exp(x))
print(f.maker.fgraph.toposort())
t0 = time.time()
for i in xrange(iters):
    r = f()
t1 = time.time()

print("Looping %d times took %f seconds" % (iters, t1 - t0))
print("Result is %s" % (r))


if numpy.any([isinstance(x.op, T.Elemwise) for x in f.maker.fgraph.toposort()]):
    print('Used the cpu')
else:
    print('Used the gpu')
```

When I run the program, it seems as if it recognizes the `GPU`, but at the end the message "used the cpu" is printed.

```
[idf@localhost python]$ python theanoexam1.py 
Mapped name None to device opencl0:0: Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 BroadWell U-Processor GT2 
[GpuElemwise{exp,no_inplace}(<GpuArrayType<None>(float32, vector)>), HostFromGpu(gpuarray)(GpuElemwise{exp,no_inplace}.0)]
Looping 1000 times took 1.231896 seconds
Result is [ 1.23178029  1.61879337  1.52278054 ...,  2.20771813  2.29967737
  1.62323284]
Used the cpu
[idf@localhost python]$
```

I am skeptical of the message "used the cpu": 1.231896 seconds seems fast for an `Intel i3` with four `cores`.

Is there an extra configuration that is needed to use `opencl` with `theano`? Or did this program indeed show that `theano` is configured to use  the `GPU` through `opencl`?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly thank you for you post.

I am running on Ubuntu 16.04, with Conda, and I have manually installed libgpuarray - all of which is well documented on the web.

I used the same test program you did (thank you for providing it).

So here are my settings

```
export MKL_THREADING_LAYER=GNU
```

The file ~/.theanorc looks like this

```
[global]
device = opencl0:0
floatX = float32

[lib]
cnmem=100
```

When I run the code

```
python test.py
```

I see the output

```
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [2]
param: 4, val: 0
Mapped name None to device opencl0:0: Ellesmere 
[GpuElemwise{exp,no_inplace}(<GpuArrayType<None>(float32, vector)>), HostFromGpu(gpuarray)(GpuElemwise{exp,no_inplace}.0)]
Looping 1000 times took 0.282664 seconds
Result is [1.2317803 1.6187935 1.5227805 ... 2.207718  2.2996776 1.6232328]
Used the gpu
```

I can not figure out how to use the 2nd GPU (also OpenCL) - but I am happy at the moment that at least I have 1 GPU running.